# If $A$ is a matrix, and $A^2=I$, then can I say that $|A|= \pm1$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

$A^2=I$

Take determinant on both sides:
$$|A^2|= |I| $$
$$|A|^2= 1$$
$$|A| = +1 \text{  or  } -1$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It means that the matrix is it's own inverse.

Comment: the determinant of a product is the product of determinants. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I know that. Wait i'll just edit my answer. To SalmonKiller that is.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Answer (score 6):

$$\det{A^2}=\det{AA}=\det{A}\det{A}=(\det{A})^2=\det{I}=1$$
$$\therefore\det{A}=\pm 1$$

Comment: Yes thank you. :)

Comment: @kay Glad I could help :) If you're satisfied with my answer, you can click the "accept answer" button next to it, so that the question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 3):

You have $1 = \text{det}I = \text{det}(A^2) = \text{det}A\text{det}A $

It follows that $\text{det}A = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

yes. the determinant have the properties that $$det(AB) = det(A)det(B), det(I) = 1.$$  therefore using the two properties we have, $$det(A^2) = \left(det(A)\right)^2 = 1 \implies det(A) = \pm 1.$$